# collapse hidden by default in html

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="tools">   
<a  id="iconoCollapsedE" title="Ocultar/Expandir" class="collapse" > </a>   
</div>   
</div>  
<div id="collap" class="portlet-body" style="overflow: auto">   
<div id="contenedorTablaLatidos">
```

Could anybody please tell me how to put the collapse option hidden by default?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add the `css`?

Comment: can you make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your requirements?

### General example:

```css
div#hidden {
  display: none;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div#visible {
  display: block;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden">I'm hidden!</div>
<div id="visible">I'm visible!</div>
```

With `display: none;` you can "hide" the element `display: none;` is applied to. It get's rendered, but not shown on the page.

### How to make it visible and make it invisible again?

You can do that with JavaScript:

```js
function collapseDiv() {
  var div = document.getElementById('hidden');
  if (div.style.display === "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    div.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
div#hidden {
  display: none;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div#visible {
  display: block;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">I'm hidden!</div>
<div id="visible">I'm visible!</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Collapse / uncollapse div" onclick="collapseDiv()">
```

### Why does this answer not use the already given code?

I'm sorry, but you didn't provide enough informations about your problem.